# Disable microphone noise gate

Tags: windows

Microphone input on my Windows PC suffers from excessive noise gating. It loses the start of most utterances and frequently drops out.

Once it starts to pick up audio input, the volume is fine.

I've experimented with various microphones and checked all the options in the Windows `Recording Devices` dialog, without success.

Note that I'm running Windows 8.1 on a Toshiba Satellite P50t and found a solution eventually. But I want this question to cover this issue for Windows in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in my case was with a noise gate feature in the `IDT High Definition Audio CODEC`.

There's a control panel called `IDT Audio Control Panel` (aka: `IDT Audio Manager`), but it doesn't expose any options for the noise gate. Disabling the 'Noise Cancellation' checkbox didn't help.

I was only able to disable the noise gate by setting `Bypass` to `1` under the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\LFX\MicIn1\presets\_initial\InputGate]
```